# IE7 problem with elements

Tags: internet-explorer-7

I got list. In every browser looks good. But in IE7 there's no line-break after displaying three elements.

Any hacks?

Comment: if you want useful answers, you should post the code.

Answer (score 0):

add the following css to your list elements

:

```
display: block;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, does not help. Tried it before.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="gallery-cont" style="width:900px; float:left;">
    <div>text></div>
    <div>text></div>
    <div>text></div>
    <div>text></div>
</div>


float:left;
height:  348px; /* 285px + 63 */
padding-right:6px !important;
margin:0px 4px 12px 4px !important; 
text-align:left;
width:285px;
clear:right;
```

It's only preview code, but it's the same.

Working correctly in FF3, Opera, Chrome and even IE8. But does not work in IE7. Child divs are displayed in one line.

Anyone?

Comment: that css, what does it go with?